# Android Hardware Scaler interpolation mode

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

Looking at the docs about `SurfaceHolder` I can't find the way to specify interpolation mode for scaling: linear vs nearest-neighbour. Is it even possible to upscale `GLSurfaceView` in hardware (fast) with nearest filtering mode?

On iOS there is a `magnificationFilter` and `minificationFilter` properties on `CALayer`.

I need this features to implement performance-friendly way of rendering true pixel art games. Basically, there are 3 options (given all art is at one pixel scale):

1. Render all textures with GL_NEAREST filter at full device resolution. This is acceptable when game objects do not rotate. With rotation this method violates pixel-grid alignment.
2. Render whole game to small texture, then fit it on screen with GL_NEAREST. Requires some overhead with rendering-to-texture.
3. Use small viewport and then make system hardware perform the scaling - blazingly fast way, that is possible on iOS. But Android is the question...

Comment: The hardware scaling from `setFixedSize()` is performed by the display hardware, not GLES, and is not programmable from the app.  (The feature is demonstrated in the "hardware scaler exerciser" activity in Grafika - https://github.com/google/grafika .)  The filter quality will vary between devices, but you can expect a reasonable-quality bilinear filter.